# How can I change the breakpoint for MegaMenu in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, responsive

I am using the MegaMenu in Magento 2. The default breakpoint for the menu to collapse is 1024px / 1025px. The smaller version is a simple list of categories, sliding in from the right side of the screen. The bigger version is a dropdown with categories to hover.

How can I change the breakpoint to 1194px / 1195px?

I tried modifying JS and CSS but it just broke the menu. I could also not find an option in the admin panel.

Comment: what is the vendor of the megamenu extension, it is an extension right?

Comment: Hello @Rustyjim, thank you for your answer. Yes, it is an extension. I did not install it myself but it should be this one: https://products.amasty.com/megamenu?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsqqb6LeB6gIVU4BQBh3lKQRhEAAYASAAEgLXWfD_BwE

Answer (score 0):

I don't own the extension but i read the javascript and in the file of demo website:

https://mega-menu-m2-ce.magento-demo.amasty.com/static/version1586867535/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Amasty_MegaMenu/js/open-type.js

Line number 35:

```
        _create: function () {
            var self = this,
                isMobile = $(window).width() <= 1024 ? 1 : 0,
                options = self.options,
                openType = options.openType,
                isHamburger = +options.hamburgerStatus;
```

There is the breakpoint (1024). Maybe if you change that to 1194 or 1195?

```
            _create: function () {
                var self = this,
                    isMobile = $(window).width() <= 1194 ? 1 : 0,
                    options = self.options,
                    openType = options.openType,
                    isHamburger = +options.hamburgerStatus;
```

Override that setting with js. or override the whole js file? Hope that helps.